# How to create development website instance to preview changes made before going live?

Tags: aws

I'd like to know if there's any way I can set up a duplicate of the live website I have running on amazon web services so that I can preview changes I'd like to make without effective the live website. So far it doesn't seem like there are any options to preview changes on expressionengine

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear what you mean here. Your question mentions creating a "development website instance" but also talk of "preview[ing] changes".

If you mean that you want to be able to preview content changes before publishing them in your live site then there are a couple of add-ons that spring to mind.

- Publisher Lite https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/publisher-lite
- Better Workflow https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/better-workflow

These will allow the creation of draft entries which need to be reviewed and publish. This is commonly referred to as "Workflow control".

If, however, you are referring to making changes to the actual build of the site (i.e. templates, add-on files etc) then the common practice would be to set up a totally separate site. When developing I would normally have a local development version, a staging (or preview) version which my client can test, and the a live (or production) version. Each uses their own database and filesystem so they do not impact one another.

At its simplest you would simply clone the site - copy the files and database and set them up somewhere else. The clone would need a different config setup.

If that is the case then you need to create a new copy of your site files and database, install them on a server and have them accessible via a different domain to your live site. This might be a local set up or a site also hosted on AWS. If this is the case then I would also advise making sure the preview site is turned off (so it is only accessible to logged in Super Admins).

Working this way means one needs to be careful about where changes are made to files and data. For instance, it is desirable to push changes to templates *up* the chain from development->staging->production but undesirable to push content/data changes. Equally, any changes to content on the production site should be passed *down* the chain from production->staging->development.

To help in managing all of this you will probably also need to use a config system such as [Focus Labs Config](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config). This will allow you to create separate configuration files for each environment which greatly simplifies deployment.